# How could I show all the AMI images

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I just want to list AMIs that I have or I can use

However, I couldn't find an easy way to do this with `aws cli`

When I type `aws ec2 describe-images --filters Name=image-type,Values=kernel`

## lots of information that I don't know how they come

[image]

## Expected results are ami-id, Name, Tag, AMI Name, Owner

[image]

Comment: please add the 'ec2' tag also because it helps when people search for questions.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. You asked for those you have and **also for those you can use**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to filter it out using the --query option in your command. 
Example: `--query 'Images[ * ].{ID:ImageId}'` will return only ImageId.
This is also explained at:
 [Describe-Images](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html) 
So, in your case, you need to do something like:

```
--query 'Images[ * ].{ID:ImageId, ImgName:Name, owner:OwnerId, tag:Description}
```

Comment: If you would prefer not to deal with the standard JSON output, add a ``--output text`` option to that command and you will get something that is easily parseable in standard shell tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can list your own images by [command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/finding-an-ami.html)

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self
```